# How to start the embedded tomcat server of spring boot and start the server in debug mode

Tags: tomcat

I need to start the embedded tomcat server of spring boot and start the server in debug mode

Answer (score 2):

You can do in `cmd` as:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n -jar <jar-name>
```

This will open the debug mode which you can connect through Eclipse by giving port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do that .

We can use maven to package the project like:

```
mvn clean package
```

and then start the server by :

```
java -jar .\target\springweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and also can start it in debug mode :

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n -jar .\target\springweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

found in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html